# Как установить opencv на ubuntu 18-ой версии для работы с языком си?

Tags: c, opencv

Всем привет, не могу найти способ установки библиотеки opencv на ubuntu 18-ой версии для написания прог на языке СИ, кучу способов перепробовал, но ничего не работает, вылетает куча неопределенных ссылок,вот фото[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне установить эту библиотеку?

Comment: opencv install ubuntu в гугле конечно ну нельзя набрать

Comment: @Andrey, вы бы набрали и посмотрели, что там пишут, там копируют с сайта на сайт один и тот же маразм, про сборку из исходников

Comment: @PavelGridin ну я как бы когда то так и делал и все норм. Если читать бездумно то да, лажа

Comment: Инклюды у вас кстати тоже не прописаны. `#include "/usr/include/...` быть не должно. @PavelGridin Это не маразм, это суровая реальность. Причем обычно приходится не просто из исходников собирать, но еще и самостоятельно патчить проблемные места.

Comment: В чем вы работаете ??  первый раз такое вижу. Также спрашивайте, если ещё остались вопросы, _как могу так и помогу :3_

Comment: Также вызов на си будет выглядеть так : `gcc -fopencv_core -fopencv_imgproc -fopencv_highgui openvc1.c -o tream`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ставим репозиторий :

```
sudo apt install libopencv-dev
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После в проекте надо установить библиотеки :

Именно тут вы и допустили ошибку, подключаетете так как будто вы работаете в виндовс, **это в корне не верно** библиотеки стоят в папке `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, а заголовочные в `/usr/include/opencv` есть ещё также `/usr/include/opencv2` но она для самой библиотеки, а не для пользователя !!!!

**Подключения должны быть прописаны !!!! так не заработает  `#include<opencv/highgui.h>` и так тоже `#include<usr/include/opencv/highgui.h>`**

В общем вот (проект собрал в QtCreator-e) :

**openvc1.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lopencv_core

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/opencv
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/opencv


unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lopencv_highgui

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/opencv
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/opencv


unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lopencv_imgproc

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/opencv
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/opencv
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include<cv.h>
#include<highgui.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// вот это код у меня так и не запустился
//int main(int argc, char* argv[])
//{
//        IplImage* image=0, *dst=0;

//        // имя картинки
//        char filename[] = "Image0.jpg";

//        // получаем картинку
//        image = cvLoadImage(filename, 1);

//        printf("[i] image: %s\n", filename);
//        assert( image != 0 );

//        // покажем изображение
//        cvNamedWindow( "image");
//        cvShowImage( "image", image );

//        // ждём нажатия клавиши
//        cvWaitKey(0);

//        // освобождаем ресурсы
//        cvReleaseImage(& image);
//        cvReleaseImage(&dst);

//        // удаляем окна
//        cvDestroyAllWindows();
//        return 0;
//}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
        // задаём высоту и ширину картинки
        int height = 620;
        int width = 440;
        // задаём точку для вывода текста
        CvPoint pt = cvPoint( height/4, width/2 );
        // Создаёи 8-битную, 3-канальную картинку
        IplImage* hw = cvCreateImage(cvSize(height, width), 8, 3);
        // заливаем картинку чёрным цветом
        cvSet(hw,cvScalar(0,0,0));
        // инициализация шрифта
        CvFont font;
        cvInitFont( &font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1.0, 1.0, 0, 1, CV_AA);
        // используя шрифт выводим на картинку текст
        cvPutText(hw, "OpenCV Step By Step", pt, &font, CV_RGB(150, 0, 150) );

        // создаём окошко
        cvNamedWindow("Hello World", 0);
        // показываем картинку в созданном окне
        cvShowImage("Hello World", hw);
        // ждём нажатия клавиши
        cvWaitKey(0);

        // освобождаем ресурсы
        cvReleaseImage(&hw);
        cvDestroyWindow("Hello World");
        return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также вот ссылки которые вам многое объяснят([первая](http://robocraft.ru/blog/computervision/435.html) , [вторая](http://robocraft.ru/blog/computervision/266.html) ), если вы работаете через **g++** то вам будет весьма удобно.

---

Также сборка в **gcc** будет выглядеть так :

```
 gcc -fopencv_core -fopencv_imgproc -fopencv_highgui openvc1.c -o tream
```

Comment: А как прописать эти подключения? Что это вообще значит?

Comment: @НиколайНиколаевич вот здесь давай [диалог продолжим](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102492/openvc----)

Answer (score 0):

Для установки OpenCV из родного репозитария надо выполнить:

```
sudo apt install libopencv-dev
```